# Why "generate_launch_description" is called two times when I start a launch file from another launch file

Tags: ros2, roslaunch, ros-humble

When I use the ros launch files I observed a phenomenon that, if I use launch file A to call launch file B, then the function of launchfile B "generate_launch_description" will be called two times, while the ros node is only executed one time.

So here I will provide my two launch files

Launch file A,  named launch_example_A.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import launch
import launch_ros.actions
from launch import LaunchDescription
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, PythonExpression, TextSubstitution

from launch.actions import (DeclareLaunchArgument, EmitEvent, ExecuteProcess,
                            LogInfo, RegisterEventHandler, TimerAction)



def generate_launch_description():

    ld = LaunchDescription()
    example_node_A = launch.actions.IncludeLaunchDescription(
        launch.launch_description_sources.PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
            get_package_share_directory('example_nodes'), 'launch'),
            '/launch_example_B.py'])
        )

    ld.add_action( example_node_A )
    return ld
```

Launch file B, named launch_example_B.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import launch
import launch_ros.actions
from launch import LaunchDescription
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, PythonExpression, TextSubstitution

from launch.actions import (DeclareLaunchArgument, EmitEvent, ExecuteProcess,
                            LogInfo, RegisterEventHandler, TimerAction)



def generate_launch_description():
    print("start launch file B")
    ld = LaunchDescription()
    example_node_B = launch.actions.IncludeLaunchDescription(
        launch.launch_description_sources.PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
            get_package_share_directory('example_nodes'), 'launch'),
            '/launch_example_C.py'])
        )

    ld.add_action( example_node_B )
    return ld
```

When I use the command ros2 launch [package_name] lauch_example_A.py, Then in the terminal I get two prints, it shows like following:

```
start launch file B
start launch file B
```

Can someone explain why it looks like this? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy, clean way to launch several other launch files, that I know works.

````
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, PathJoinSubstitution, PythonExpression
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
# from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare
# from launch.conditions import IfCondition, UnlessCondition


def generate_launch_description():
    lino2_launch_path = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [FindPackageShare('linorobot2_bringup'), 'launch', 'bringup.launch.py']
    )

    velodyne_launch_path = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [FindPackageShare('velodyne'), 'launch', 'velodyne-all-nodes-VLP16-composed-launch.py']
    )

    rtabmap_launch_path = '/home/rod/rtabmap_slam.launch.py'


    return LaunchDescription([

        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(lino2_launch_path),
            
        ),

        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(velodyne_launch_path),
                      
        ),
        
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(rtabmap_launch_path),
            
        )

    ])
```
````

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I have tried with your launch script and it has the same phenomenon. You can try it by yourself. Just print some stuff in bringup.launch.py after the def generate_launch_description():, you will see that it prints two times

Answer (score 0):

I find one Issue that the ros developer explained it a little bit. It seems like it exits and they consider it as not a bug.
https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/1283

So finally my solution looks like this:
In the launch_example_B.py, I excute my command by using ExecuteProcess

```
def generate_launch_description():
  # print("start launch file B")
 # The my_cmd can be replaced with some commands which need to be executed.

    ld = LaunchDescription([
                     DeclareLaunchArgument(name='open_gui', default_value='False'),
                     ExecuteProcess(
                         cmd=['my_cmd'],
                         #condition=IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration('open_gui')),
                     ), 
                ])

    # > start example_node_C
    example_node_B = launch.actions.IncludeLaunchDescription(
    launch.launch_description_sources.PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('example_nodes'), 'launch'),
        '/launch_example_C.py'])
    )

ld.add_action( example_node_B )

    return ld
```